# Loop that begins at Active Cell

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to create a loop that will always begin at the active cell?

Here is an example of what I am thinking.

```
Sub Highlight()

i = 1
Do While Cells(i, ActiveColumn).Value <> ""
    If Cells(i, ActiveColumn).Value = 0 Then
       Cells(i, ActiveColumn).Value = 3
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Obviously this code does not work. Cells(i, ActiveColumn) is not a real reference.

Comment: `Cells(i, Activecell.column)` But relying on the active cell is not advisable.

Comment: ^^ and, if you also want `i` to start at `ActiveCell.Row`, replace `i = 1` with `i = ActiveCell.Row`.

Comment: Works great! thanks SJR. Is there anyway to use offset in the reference as well?    Cells(i, Activecell.offset(0,-1)

Comment: You could just use `Activecell.offset(0,-1)` which returns a range so no need for Cells. Depends on what you are actually trying to achieve. Or just use Find and Replace?